# How to convert scala function as parameter in c++?

Tags: c++, scala, function, functional-programming, function-parameter

So I would like to implement functional programming in c++, just as it would be done in scala.

So lets say I have this code snippet in scala:

```scala
def exampleA(l: List[P], f: P => Option[P]): Option[P] = l match {
  case Nil => None
  case x :: l => val a = f(x); if ( a.notDefined ) exampleA(l, f) else a
}
```

It takes in a list of P, and **`a function as parameter`**. It will return the first element in a list.

Now I would like to approach the same way in C++, and I am already confused, because there is not information regarding calling function as parameter.

So this is what I have so far:

```cpp
typedef vector<pair<int,int> > P;

P exampleB( P (*f)(int,Path) ) {
  cout << (*f)->first << endl;
}


P exampleBA(int dim, Path path) {
  exampleB(exampleBA);
}
```

I would like to access the **`first`** element of pair inside **`P`** inside **`example()`** method.

How can I do this?

Comment: I would not sugest to use the same style in c++ as in scala. They are different beasts and if your code is used by c++ programers they will be a little confused. You know... when in Rome, do what romans do.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/function-pointers.html

But the recomended way in c++11 is std:: function: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function